# ODBC: SQLDescribeCol always return columnNameLength of 0

Tags: sql-server, odbc, sql-server-2014, windows-server-2012

For some reason, ODBC `SQLDescribeCol()` always returns `columnNameLength` of `0`, which screws up the logic of the code.

Running in Windows Server 2012 and SQLServer 2014 Developer.

Any idea why is it always returning `columnNameLength` of `0`?

The [code is here](https://github.com/szekerest/mapserver/blob/intramaps/mapmssql2008.c#L615).

[image: debugging]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turned out to be an issue for x64 build, where the parameters' sizes was incorrectly coded (it should be SQLULEN instead of SQLUINTEGER)

https://github.com/szekerest/mapserver/commit/6eb767fcaecd03960940343f9acef2ce296caf70

[image: fix]

Answer (score 1):

Two things:

- ODBC might not be at fault, but the ODBC driver you are using. Might be a bug or one of those "features" which are "optional".
- Even if the driver returns 0 for the length, `columnName` still contains a null-terminated string. Don't know much about C#, but I bet there is a way to create a string object from that. Or you could count try to find the null termination character yourself. In any case, since your external `buffer` needs to be large enough to hold the largest supported column name, copying the entire `columnName` buffer should be ok either way.

That being said, I think if you improved your function to just return a string object, you would be much better off. Less (pointer) parameters, a meaningful return value, and error handling with exceptions. Just a suggestion, though.

Comment: thanks Michael, this turned out to be an issue for x64 build and param size  going into SQQLDescribeCol